# How to speed up EF Core query when it comes to a large database table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using a dbcontext with DI.  I can query the 14,000 records in the database via SQL Server Management Studio in under 2 seconds.

However, when I run it with either Swagger or Postman, it eventually times out. Someone said to use `IQueryable`, not as a list, but I am unsure how to do the foreach using `IQueryable` as I've done with the below list.

Also, when looking at the memory, the usage shoots up to almost 16 out of 16 gig. The below definitely does work for a smaller amount of rows but I noticed when it hit over 5,000 rows is when it laughs at me.

How can I speed this up and get it to give me the 14,000 records and also with little to no memory usage. Another gentleman recommended splitting the query across multiple threads. I have no idea how to do that either :/

`EventsManagementService`:

```
public EventsManagementService(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
{
    _applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;
}

public async Task<List<LogStore>> GetEvents(CancellationToken token)
{
    List<LogStore> events = new List<LogStore>();
    var getEvents = await Task.Run(() => _applicationDbContext.LogStore.ToListAsync(), token);

    foreach (var log in getEvents)
    {
        events.Add(new LogStore
        {
            Id = log.Id,
            Keywords = log.Keywords,
            EventId = log.EventId,
            Publisher = log.Publisher?.Replace("-", " "),
            TimeStamp = log.TimeStamp,
            Description = log.Description,
            ContainerLog = log.ContainerLog,
            TaskCategory = log.TaskCategory,
            Level = log.Level,

        });
    }

    return events.ToList();
}
```

`EventsController`:

```
[HttpGet("GetEvents")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<LogStore>>> GetEvents(CancellationToken token)
{
    List<LogStore> events = await Task.Run(() => 
        _eventsManagementService.GetEvents(token), HttpContext.RequestAborted);

    return Ok(new { data = events.OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeStamp) });
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster. The MCVE should clearly show the performance issue when executed.

Comment: This call here `return events.ToList();` is pointless, since `events` already is a `List<T>` and you're filling it with instantiated objects. Just `return events` would be sufficient (but I suspect that won't really change performance....)

Comment: But the main question really is: `_applicationDbContext.LogStore.ToListAsync()` **already** returns a `List<LogStore>` - why do you even iterate over that list to create new `LogStore` objects again? Can't you just use `return getEvents` and be done with it?

Comment: Thanks Marc. This was a project started by a previous employee and myself and another gentleman took it over to finish it.  I simply misunderstood what the original guy was doing but have since corrected it using Steve's suggestion below and it works pretty well and responsive now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question is why would you ever want to return 14,000+ records in a single call? If this is going to a UI consider server-side pagination with a page # and page size to return more meaningful blocks of data to be consumed. A method like this will only get slower and slower as the system ages and accumulates rows.

As for performance you have a lot of unnecessary steps to return the data. The easiest "fix" for run time and memory usage with a cancellation token would be to simplify it to this:

```
public async Task<List<LogStore>> GetEvents(CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        var events = await _applicationDbContext.LogStore
            .AsNoTracking()
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp)
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken: token);
        return events;
    }
    catch(OperationCancelledException)
    { // Consider anything you want to happen if cancellation token tripped.
        return new List<LogStore>();
    }
}
```

The `async` methods in EF Core already support cancellation tokens. Since you want to return the entities we don't need the DbContext to cache or otherwise return tracked instances so use `AsNoTracking()` to avoid the overhead memory/time to track the entities that are loaded. Also move the order by condition into the Linq expression when the data is read, not in the controller after the data is materialized. If you have different ordering requirements pass it into the service as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you Steve, applying your solution dropped the memory usage down into the low 100s of meg.  It's a small app to retain logs for 6 months.  We have custom filtering on the UI looking for specific like "contains user", "date/time", etc, but also the option to see all logs for the past 6 months.

Comment: Definitely read up on server-side pagination where you would use a pagination control and send a page # and page size with your request and load 25-100 or so records at a time, or even more if users might want to scroll through a history looking at a bigger picture. Even loading 1000 at a time will be a lot more performant than 14k+ as the system use grows.

Answer (score 1):

To deal with large number of data and improve performance you can follow below suggestion:

You can modify your method to return `IQueryable<LogStore>`. This way, the query is not executed until you actually enumerate over the results, allowing for more efficient memory usage and potentially faster execution.

```
public IQueryable<LogStore> GetEvents()
   {
       return _applicationDbContext.LogStore;
   }
```

You can utilize async streams in C# 8.0 and later to asynchronously stream data, reducing memory footprint.

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<LogStore> GetEventsAsync(CancellationToken token)
   {
       await foreach (var log in _applicationDbContext.LogStore.AsAsyncEnumerable().WithCancellation(token))
       {
           yield return log;
       }
   }
```

In your controller, you should avoid loading all data into memory. If you need to apply additional processing like sorting, consider doing it at the database level using `IQueryable`.

```
[HttpGet("GetEvents")]
   public async Task<ActionResult> GetEvents(CancellationToken token)
   {
       await foreach (var log in _eventsManagementService.GetEventsAsync(token))
       {
           // Process each log item here, or directly stream it to the response
           // This avoids loading all data into memory
       }
       return Ok(); // Adjust as needed for your response format
   }
```

If you don't need all 14,000 records at once, consider implementing pagination. This way, you can fetch a manageable subset of records at a time.Splitting the query across multiple threads (i.e., parallel processing) can be beneficial in some scenarios, but it's complex and may not always lead to better performance, especially with database queries. Databases are often the bottleneck, and hammering it with parallel queries can make things worse. In your case, streaming the results with `IQueryable` should be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you Jalpa, I will also test your solution as well.   This is a small app to retain logs for 6 months. We have custom filtering on the UI looking for specific like "contains user", "date/time", etc, but also the option to see all logs for the past 6 months.  I appreciate your help too.